# How to integerate your aws credentials file in codepipeline as I cannot save it in Github repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

Project is built using AWS lambda and some other AWS services. In order to make a build and just to serve a build static files through node express server, it requires the credentials.js file which contains all my AWS credentials of the project.
Now I' making creating an aws codepipeline which pulls the code from GitHub and deploys it on ec2 using elastic beanstalk.
The problem is I don't push my credentials file on Github as it is not secure to do so. And without credentials file the code cannot be deployed. Please suggest me a solution to this problem.

I have already tried placing the file manually in ec2 instance by logging in, but when I make a commit to my repo, the code pipeline executes and it replaces the whole directory of my app in ec2, so the file gets removed.

Comment: What point is it failing at? In the credentials file is it only AWS credentials, or other secrets? You shouldn’t need the credentials file to simply deploy it as the EB service role will handle that. For anything else, best practice is to assign a role to the function or instance and grant that role access to the necessary resources. For other secrets, setup some Elastic Beanstalk environment variables and reference the env var in your code. See this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can securely store your credentials config file in a private S3 bucket and add `commands` to your `buildspec.yml` file (used by the CodeBuild stage of your pipeline) to get that file and put it in the right place for your project.

You will need to give the CodeBuild service role the correct permissions to access the private S3 bucket.

The following is an example of what I mean. Note that I might be storing the config file for multiple environments in S3, so I use an environment variable to specify the exact naming of the file, e.g. `my-creds.dev.json` or `my-creds.prod.json`. The filename is then converted to just `my-creds.json` so you can rely on the same name in your program.

*CodeBuild will look for buildspec.yml which defines your build in the root of your project and execute these commands*

```
version: 0.2  

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # Get the creds config file for the correct environment
      # and put it in the my projects config directory (or wherever you need it)
      - aws s3 cp s3://my-s3-bucket/my-creds.${ENVIRONMENT}.json ./config/my-creds.json
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build:${ENVIRONMENT}

artifacts:
  files:
    - dist/**/*
```

The critical line is `aws s3 cp s3://my-s3-bucket/my-creds.${ENVIRONMENT}.json ./config/my-creds.json`.

- The commands are run in the root of your project directory, where the `buildspec.yml` file is.
- The above command is in the `pre_build` phase so it will run before the commands (npm build) in the `build` phase are run.
- The command copies your credential file from your s3 bucket to the path defined by the last part of the command (in this case `./config/my-creds.json`). Again remember this is relative to the root of your project directory, so if your project contains a `src` folder in the root directory, then your path might be `./src/my-creds.json`, or `./src/creds/my-creds.json`.

Comment: I got the idea you are trying to deliver, I just have one confusion now, how it is going to place the file in the correct location before build.                                                         
I mean to ask where we are defining path, to place the file?

Comment: @HassanIrshad I've updated the answer, but in short the path and name of the destination for your config file is defined by the last argument to the `aws s3 cp` command. In the example give, it is going to the `./confg` directory (relative to the root of your project) and will be renamed from `my-creds.[some-environment].json` to `my-creds.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the credentials file as it is not recommended. You can do the deployment by assigning a role to your code pipeline with permission to access the required resources.